# How can I combine `raco pkg install --scope-dir` and `raco exe`?

Tags: racket, raco

I have an application that creates Racket programs, and uses `raco exe`/`raco distribute` to distribute them.

The Racket programs that my application creates also depend on a Racket library "x" which I can bundle with my application, and which needs to be `raco pkg install`ed in order to build and distribute the later programs.

However, I don't want to interfere with a system- or user-scoped Racket setup, nor do I want my installation of "x" to be interfered with by a system- or user-scoped Racket setup.

I've seen that I can `raco pkg install --auto --scope-dir <myapp/share/racket> "x"`, but `raco exe` doesn't accept a corresponding `--scope-dir` command, so I guess I don't really get it.

Can I install packages somewhere private and use still use them with `raco exe`? Or what can I do?